Adding a "door open" alarm when handbrake is on?
Old ute owner here, retrofitting some locked cabinets to my rear tray and was hoping to fit some sort of alarm when the door is open on the tray. Got myself a cheap 12V alarm beeper and a relay, my thinking is that if my tray doors are left open, I could have it connected up alongside a relay and the handbrake circuit so that it will set the alarm off if the Handbrake is down AND the tray door is open.
I'm unfortunately struggling with how I'd design this circuit? If anyone has any ideas that would be amazing!
Edit: forgot to mention I also have a small push button similar to this which would really be doing the "sensing part"of whether the door was open or closed : https://btw-electronics.net/product/miniature-push-button-switches/

You'll need to add two relays in series - in an 'and' setup.
This means that both relays need to close their switches to allow the buzzer to work.
The handbrake switch should drive a double acting relay that flops from one contact to the other, the toolbox door switch should drive a normal relay that switches on when the door opens.
When both the handbrake is in the 'off' position and the toolbox doors are open, the buzzer will sound.
